# midnight commander: sort directories by name and files by date?

Tags: mc

Is it possible to sort directories by name, and files by date, at the same time?  It is easy to obtain this behavior in Total Commander, which I find very nice.
Thanks.

Comment: Formal note: any directory is also a [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690); it's a file of the type directory. I understand you mean "directories by name and non-directories by date".

Comment: Yeah, patch the sources. I'm not joking, your request is quite unusual and unlikely to be ever implemented.